# Xaml Image.Source is not updating in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I have some trouble with updating the source of an Image in Xaml. Im making a Windows Store App, and Im trying to set the source in my C# code. Basically, what my small program is doing is to let the user select a JPG file, and then copy this over to AppData folder. In my App, I want the picture the user have uploaded to show. Everything is working except the part where I show the image, this image does not want to change even if I provide a new source.

C# Code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    FileOpenPicker pickerSelect;
    FileSavePicker pickerSave;

    StorageFolder folder;
    StorageFile pic;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        InitializePickers();
        InitializeProfilePicture();
    }

    private async void InitializeProfilePicture()
    {
        folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;    
        pic = await folder.GetFileAsync("profile.jpg");        

        BitmapImage uri = new BitmapImage(new Uri(pic.Path, UriKind.Absolute));
        ProfilePic.Source = uri;

    }

    private void InitializePickers()
    {
        pickerSelect = new FileOpenPicker();
        pickerSave = new FileSavePicker();
        pickerSelect.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

    }


    private async void Upload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFile pictureSelect = await pickerSelect.PickSingleFileAsync();
        StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        await pictureSelect.CopyAsync(folder, "profile.jpg", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        InitializeProfilePicture();
    }
}
```

In the method "InitializeProfilePicture" I create a new BitmapImage and I set ProfilePic to this. This code is just working once, if I run the InitializeProfilePicture in the start as I do now, and the user selects a new picture and uploads to the AppData folder, the image does not change (even though the picture is indeed uploaded). If I remove the method from the start and just keep it in the Button_Click method, the new uploaded picture will be the one showing. But uploading a new picture after ProfilePic have set it's source, it will not change.

Image in Xaml is just like this

```
Image Width="480" Height="640" x:Name="ProfilePic" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"
```

.. And there is also a button here to run Upload_Click method, but thats it.

Any idea why this is happening?? Should it not be updated??

Comment: That is because the image is cached when it is created from an Uri. Creating a new BitmapImage with the same file path will return the cached image. You should open a file stream and call the BitmapImage's `SetSource` or `SetSourceAsync` method.

Comment: I suspected it was related to cache.. I have played a little with the SetSource, but I didnt get it to work. How would this look in code??

Comment: Why don't you just create the BitmapImage from the selected picture's path, i.e. `pictureSelect.Path`?

Comment: This actually sounds like a clever workaround. I gave it one attempt now, but the Image changed to nothing, even though the path is valid... I really cant stand working with paths.. Im off this stuff for today, but I will give it a better try tomorrow with some debugging. Thanks for your suggestions so far :)

Comment: Loading a BitmapImage from a local file Uri doesn't seem to work. However, you can easily load an image directly from a file stream. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load a BitmapImage directly from file like this:

```
var imageFile = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = await imageFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
    await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}

ProfilePic.Source = bitmap;
```